# windows phone 7 button in longlistselector

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I've read somewhere that longlistselector from the toolkit is better in performance than the existing listbox. So, I changed the listbox to longlistselector. Now I have a image button control to keep in the longlistselector  (that acts like a checkbox). When I click on the  button, the list selection changed event is fired along with the button click. The button in listbox works fine as expected but not in longlistselector. How can I stop the list selection changed event? I searched a lot on this but couldn't find anything useful. First of all is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't take it for granted that the long list selector performs better than the listbox. The listbox uses a virtualizing stack panel when binding is involved and is pretty performant. I went down the road of using the list picker from the toolkit and ended up regretting it due to some bad performance problems. If it works with the listbox I'd say stick with the listbox and only move away if you find you have perfomance issues in the future.

Comment: please note that th `ListBox` only virtualizes when bound to a collection which implements `IList`.

Answer (score 0):

When a button is clicked a button event handler is triggered and when a item in the long list selector is changed the corresponding selection changed event is triggered IF it is also registered. But the button is clicked on the same selected item, only the button event handler is triggered. I suggest to have only a button event handler and get the selected item from it.

```
private void ButtonEvent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      HoldingClass clicked=((sender as Button).DataContext as HoldingClass);
      //Do something with the HoldingClass as this is the binding element to the long list       selector
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the ClickMode to Press in XAML

```
ClickMode="Press"
```

and inside you Click event handler make (YourListName).SelectedItem = null;

```
    private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem = null;

        ..
    }
```