# LongListSelector - button click event bubbling up to SelectionChanged event

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

This question was [previously posted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400748/windows-phone-7-button-in-longlistselector) but unfortunately no answer. I am having the same issue. Basically I have a LongListSelector and in the item template I have a button. When the button is tapped the Click event for the button is fired and then the SelectionChanged event fires.

This behavior did not happen when I was using ListBox. Any idea how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

When a button is clicked a button event handler is triggered and when a item in the long list selector is changed the corresponding selection changed event is triggered IF it is also registered. But the button is clicked on the same selected item, only the button event handler is triggered. I suggest to have only a button event handler and get the selected item from it.

```
private void ButtonEvent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
HoldingClass clicked=((sender as Button).DataContext as HoldingClass);
//Do something with the HoldingClass as this is the binding element to the long list selector
}
```